# Speed of Merkle Root proofs in SPV

Tags: merkle-tree, spv

Is it really more efficient to use the Merkle Root proofs system to verify that a transaction is included in a block for SPV clients compared to Download the block and check if the transaction is included in it and discard the block afterwards ?
(Both case does not sync the full Blockchain)